# checking solutions for differential equations after dividing by a variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with figuring out how to check solutions after dividing by a variable

example:

$$ y' = y $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = y $$
$$ \int \frac{dy}{y} = \int dx$$ 
I divided by y so I assume: $$ y \ne 0 $$

this leads to the solution

$$ y=Ce^x $$

now I have to check if y=0 is a solution. how exactly do I do it?

any Insight will be helpful.

Comment: strictly speaking, the current answers do not address the case that $y(t) = 0$ only for some $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> now I have to check if y=0 is a solution. how exactly do I do it?

You plug it in!

If $y=0$ then $y' = \ldots$; now substitute into the differential equation and notice that:

> $y' = y$ is satisfied and $y=0$ is indeed a solution.

Comment: can you please show me how? i know I'm dumb I study physics not math ;)

Comment: @segevp But it's (almost completely) there... If $y=0$, then $y'=0$, so $y'=y$ is valid and $y=0$ indeed satisfies the differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Whats the derivative of a constant? Just plug 0 to your original equation and see if it satisfies it

Comment: the derivative is 0. so i just plug in zero to y'=y and i get 0=0?

Comment: what if I want to check x=0 for example? I find y in that case and do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Take a moment to think about your assumptions.  As others mentioned, typically you take your solution and put it back in the original differential equation and verify the result (no issue here).  But $y(x)$ is never zero unless $C=0$ or $x=-\infty$, in which case your original differential equation is still valid (the latter shown by taking the limit).

Comment: thanks. I think I got it now